# GCP AI Platform pipelines kubeflow pipeline is created but can't open pipeline dashboard

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubeflow

I'm following [AI Platform Pipelines tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/pipelines/docs/getting-started) to create a Kubeflow pipeline at GCP. First time it worked then I deleted everything as described in the tutorial and tried to create again. Pipeline was created and status of it is ok but I'm getting following error when I click **OPEN PIPELINES DASHBOARD**.

[image]

Status of the Clusters under Kubernetes Engine is also ok. But Kubernetes Applications status is **Application Failed**. All components of Application are also OK.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have some error logs or error messages from the console?

Comment: No unfortunately, more interesting part is, after deleting and deploying several times, the error disappeared and it started to work.

Comment: So, actually is it working? Weird... Did you changed anything?

Comment: No, I didn't . Might be fixed

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, the issue was solved after re-deploy the application.